# Extrema of $f(x)=tx^2+e^{-x}$

Tags: real-analysis

I cannot seem to find the extrema of the function $f(x)=tx^2+e^{-x}, t>0$. The function's graph suggests that there exists a minimum. The derivative is $f'(x)=2tx-e^{-x}$ and $f'(x)=0 \Leftrightarrow -x = \ln(2t) + \ln(x)$.

Comment: There is no closed form solution since it's in the form (log(x) + x = c). It's the lambert W function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hint: we have $$f''(x)=2t+e^{-x}>0$$ for all reals $x$ and $$t>0$$

Comment: That means that the original function is convex and my derivative is monotonically increasing. Anything else? I do not see why this is helpful yet.

Comment: write your equation in the form $$2t=\frac{e^{-x}}{x}$$ and discusse the function $$\frac{e^{-x}}{x}$$ and you will get how many solutions are exist

Comment: I see, thank you. Though, I thought I was missing an easy way to find an exact value for the minimum as I found this problem in a High School textbook. But it seems there might have been a literal mistake.